# qgis-bin.exe has stopped working after changing symbol selector?

Tags: qgis, symbology

i am having troubles with QGIS 2.6.1.  It crashes when i try to change the symbol selector within each vector layer.  If it doesnt crash it seems that the changes i have made in symbol selector do not display.  see screen shot below for more info.

crash error message: qgis-bin.exe has stopped working.  a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Perhaps a memory problem? Try disabling all other layers (especially OpenLayers) and then edit your symbology.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joseph.  I tried disabling all other layer, including OpenLayers with no success.  It still crashed.  It seems to do one of several things. If i change the first category symbol (usually no problem), when i try to change the second category symbol it either crashes, doesn't take effect or changes and undoes my first category symbol change.

Comment: I found a work around. I made the symbols of the remaining vector layers (polygons not points) more simple.  I only changed the simple fill to a pattern instead of adding another level to the symbol and adding a line pattern fill as well.

Comment: Very strange but glad you have a workaround.