# "QGIS-BIN.EXE has stopped working" error after QGIS run

Tags: qgis

After installing QGIS 2.18.7.1 on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine, when I run QGIS I have the following message: "QGIS-BIN.EXE has stopped working"

Do you have the solution to the problem?

I tested version 2.18.4, 2.18.6 ==> IDEM same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227538/qgis-bin-exe-has-stopped-to-work and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133013/qgis-bin-exe-has-stopped-working-after-changing-symbol-selector and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231772/qgis-bin-exe-has-stopped-working . Please provide further details in your question.

Comment: Did you use the 32-bit installer?

Comment: j'ai installé la version 32 bits et 64 bits

Comment: @maxime - Try `C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/qgis.bat`

Comment: j'ai testé la méthode : C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/qgis.bat ==> Idem même erreur lors de l'ouverture.

j'ai un Windows 7 32Bits j'ai installé le setup : QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.7-1-Setup-x86